# docker service on ec2 prevent SSH from working

Tags: linux, docker, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to start an ec2 (Amazon Linux) with this user-data script :

```sh
#cloud-boothook
#!/bin/sh
set +x
yum update -y
amazon-linux-extras install docker
service docker enable
usermod -a -G docker ec2-user
service docker start
```

But with this last line, I'm unable to SSH to the VM. If I remove it, it works. But if I start it from SSH, I loose the connection immediately.

I guess it has something to do with the fact I'm connecting from a private network, and that the VM is running in a private network as well.

Some co-workers actually got some success by setting something like this in the init script:

```sh
mkdir /etc/docker
chmod 0777 /etc/docker
echo -n '{"bip": "xxxxx", "ipv6": false, "fixed-cidr": "xxxxxx", "default-address-pools" : [{"base" : "xxxxxx", "size" : 24}]}' > /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

It actually solves the issue and works when I start the docker service manually after ssh (no connection drop anymore), but I can't get anything but a connection refused after the ec2 initialization once I copy the code into the init script.

What is the impact of these fields ? And what could be differences between the initialization, and after it which provoke different behaviours ?

Comment: I cant able to SSH to ubuntu machine after adding this line #cloud-boothook in my userdata script.